# Uniswap V3 protocol tick price conversions

Tags: blockchain, uniswapv3, math

Right now, I'm delving into the mathematics and corresponding code of the Uniswap v3 protocol, and I've stumbled upon this function. Despite scouring numerous documents and forums, I haven't found any insights. Does anyone know how to grasp the math behind it and the significance of these seemingly magical numbers like 0xfffcb933bd6fad37aa2d162d1a594001, as well as how they're derived?

```
public static getSqrtRatioAtTick(tick: number): JSBI {
invariant(tick >= TickMath.MIN_TICK && tick <= TickMath.MAX_TICK && Number.isInteger(tick), 'TICK')
const absTick: number = tick < 0 ? tick * -1 : tick

let ratio: JSBI =
  (absTick & 0x1) != 0
    ? JSBI.BigInt('0xfffcb933bd6fad37aa2d162d1a594001')
    : JSBI.BigInt('0x100000000000000000000000000000000')
if ((absTick & 0x2) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xfff97272373d413259a46990580e213a')
if ((absTick & 0x4) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xfff2e50f5f656932ef12357cf3c7fdcc')
if ((absTick & 0x8) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xffe5caca7e10e4e61c3624eaa0941cd0')
if ((absTick & 0x10) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xffcb9843d60f6159c9db58835c926644')
if ((absTick & 0x20) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xff973b41fa98c081472e6896dfb254c0')
if ((absTick & 0x40) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xff2ea16466c96a3843ec78b326b52861')
if ((absTick & 0x80) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xfe5dee046a99a2a811c461f1969c3053')
if ((absTick & 0x100) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xfcbe86c7900a88aedcffc83b479aa3a4')
if ((absTick & 0x200) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xf987a7253ac413176f2b074cf7815e54')
if ((absTick & 0x400) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xf3392b0822b70005940c7a398e4b70f3')
if ((absTick & 0x800) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xe7159475a2c29b7443b29c7fa6e889d9')
if ((absTick & 0x1000) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xd097f3bdfd2022b8845ad8f792aa5825')
if ((absTick & 0x2000) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0xa9f746462d870fdf8a65dc1f90e061e5')
if ((absTick & 0x4000) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0x70d869a156d2a1b890bb3df62baf32f7')
if ((absTick & 0x8000) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0x31be135f97d08fd981231505542fcfa6')
if ((absTick & 0x10000) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0x9aa508b5b7a84e1c677de54f3e99bc9')
if ((absTick & 0x20000) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0x5d6af8dedb81196699c329225ee604')
if ((absTick & 0x40000) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0x2216e584f5fa1ea926041bedfe98')
if ((absTick & 0x80000) != 0) ratio = mulShift(ratio, '0x48a170391f7dc42444e8fa2')

if (tick > 0) ratio = JSBI.divide(MaxUint256, ratio)

// back to Q96
return JSBI.greaterThan(JSBI.remainder(ratio, Q32), ZERO)
  ? JSBI.add(JSBI.divide(ratio, Q32), ONE)
  : JSBI.divide(ratio, Q32)
```

}

```
function mulShift(val: JSBI, mulBy: string): JSBI {
return JSBI.signedRightShift(JSBI.multiply(val, JSBI.BigInt(mulBy)), JSBI.BigInt(128))
}
```